# Yii 1.x Response Always Return with Additional Character

Tags: json, yii

I created new method action in Yii Controller. This action returns JSON formatted string.

Simple ex:

```
public function actionUpload() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $this->layout = false;
    echo (json_encode([
        'file-1' => [
             'url' => 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
        ]
    ]));

    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

But, in response, I always got additional character that makes my JSON invalid.

Simple response can be seen from this image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8WUL.png (see red dot as \efeff char).

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> (see red dot as \efeff char)

This is probably [`ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm). So basically this is invisible character and you have it hidden in one of your files (probably before `<?php` tag). Try use some IDE search or grep to localize this file and remove this invisible character.

Also there are some CS tools that may fix this issue in your codebase. For example [`php-cs-fixer`](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) has `non_printable_character` fixer which will find and remove such chars from your code.